# Why will this not load into MySQL with the table date import wizard?

Tags: mysql, excel

[Excel data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DsmNs.png)

[Table import](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iTtEU.png)

Trying to import this data and It's formatted correctly but none of the records will load, any suggestions?

```
CREATE TABLE store (
store_sale_id int DEFAULT NULL, 
store_id int DEFAULT NULL, 
store_establish_dt datetime DEFAULT NULL, 
store_lvl_cd text,
store_mgr_nm text,
store_mgr_phone_no text,
store_nm text,
store_no int DEFAULT NULL,
store_postal_cd int DEFAULT NULL,
store_postal_st text,
store_street_ad text
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;
```

Comment: Without seeing what is the error message it is nearly impossible for one to help you out. Please share whatever error message Workbench (assuming here based on your screenshot) is giving you. Also share your table (the target) structure and PLEASE do not use images run `show create table whatever_is_your_table_name` and add the result here in your question.

Comment: CREATE TABLE `store` (
   `store_sale_id` int DEFAULT NULL,
   `store_id` int DEFAULT NULL,
   `store_establish_dt` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
   `store_lvl_cd` text,
   `store_mgr_nm` text,
   `store_mgr_phone_no` text,
   `store_nm` text,
   `store_no` int DEFAULT NULL,
   `store_postal_cd` int DEFAULT NULL,
   `store_postal_st` text,
   `store_street_ad` text
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci                     There is no error message it just imports 0 of the records and creates the table.

Comment: Do not add details in comments. Instead, [edit] your post to include them there where they become part of the question. Comments are not permanent or searchable. Also, CREATE TABLE does not attempt to import data - it does only what it's name suggests, which is to create a table.

Comment: If it is not giving you any error visible error I would look for the logs of Workbench. Another thing that may be happening is your Mysql is not configured correctly to use the LOAD Data feature, see the docs here https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html